# Codemirror in vite react?

Tags: reactjs, vite, codemirror

how to install Codemirror in vite react ?

i have tried with `npm install react-codemirror2 --legacy-peer-deps` but not working and its shows the error

```
Failed to resolve import "codemirror/lib/codemirror.css" from "src\Editor.jsx". Does the file exist?
D:/projects/Mini reacts/codeweb/src/Editor.jsx:2:7
17 |  var _s = $RefreshSig$();
18 |  import React, { useState } from "react";
19 |  import "codemirror/lib/codemirror.css";
   |          ^
20 |  import "codemirror/theme/material.css";
21 |  import "codemirror/mode/xml/xml";
```

Answer (score 1):

i have tried with npm install react-codemirror2 --legacy-peer-deps after that
npm install codemirror@5
its working in both vite and creacte-react-app.
i read from here..
https://discuss.codemirror.net/t/module-not-found-error/5510/6